# Search and add Facebook friend using Phonegap

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, contacts, friend

I'm trying to develop an iOS app which delivers this functionality: Using a person's contact information such as Name, Phone number and/or email address, search said person's Facebook profile and send them a Friend Request.

More to the point, I understand I can send friend request if I know the person's FBID; however, I haven't found a method to search for a person's FBID using this info. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the profile is public you can use this for email:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=alias@domain.com&type=user
```

You can also replace the email address with a phone number